# how to post data to sqs queue url through command Line using curl command

Tags: python, curl, command-line-interface

I have an amazon simple queuing services queue.

I want to post some text message to test this queue.

Is there any way to post some message using curl command to message queue URL

queue URL:https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/859444864285/testqueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use curl commandline like this example.

```
curl -H 'Accept:application/json' -d "key=value&key1=value1" http://www.example.com/
```

More about the curl commandline option is at [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Also you can traverse the question from [stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) regarding this curl.